# Repeating notification - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How can I schedule a monthly or weekly notification in flutter? The purpose is for it to act as a reminder for the user about something...

here is my code

```
void showMonthlyAtDayTime() async {
  //var scheduledNotificationDateTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 10));
  var time = Time(12, 6, 0);
  var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'alarm_notif',
    'Scheduled notification', // name of the notif channel
    'A scheduled notification', // description of the notif channel
    icon: 'question',
    largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('question'),
  );

  var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails( 
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true);
  var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showMonthlyAtDayTime(
      0, 
      'Title',
      'Body',
      Day.Tuesday,
      time, 
      platformChannelSpecifics);
}
```

The code has (red) underline beneath the showMonthlyAtDayTime in the

'wait flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showMonthlyAtDayTime' line

and the 'Day.Tuesday' line...

How should I modify the above code? so that the user will get notification once per each month of every year about something.

Comment: Why don't you use push notification to achieve the same rather than creating notification from frontend.

Comment: how do you do that? Im a beginner in Flutter development

Comment: You can check out this video https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/

Comment: I have just updated the question description... the thing about fire flutter, Im having a lot of trouble integrating with firebase... I'm not sure why, it's not the code, but the pod file cases...

Comment: You don't need to use remote (PUSH) notifications for reminders. Scheduled reminders is better to create with local notifications without server side. So you are on the right way if you use flutter_local_notifications plugin. Why it doesn't work - there could be several reasons. Please check that you don't miss anything from plugin's settings -  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-android-setup and https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-ios-setup

Answer (score 2):

Some methods have been removed in the latest versions.

This is the code I found to repeat a notification weekly using flutter_local_notifications.

```
Future<void> _scheduleWeeklyTenAMNotification() async {
await notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    0,
    'weekly scheduled notification title',
    'weekly scheduled notification body',
    _nextInstanceOfTenAM(),
    const NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'weekly notification channel id',
          'weekly notification channel name',
          'weekly notificationdescription'),
    ),
    androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
    UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime);
  }
  tz.TZDateTime _nextInstanceOfTenAM() {
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate =
    tz.TZDateTime(tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day, 10);
    if (scheduledDate.isBefore(now)) {
      scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }
    return scheduledDate;
  }
```

this code is copied from the example app provided by https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

here is the git hub link [click Here](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications/example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a propery RepeatInterval.weekly inside of your flutterLocalNotificationPlugin.periodicallyShow.

You can also set it to everyMinute, or hourly, or daily, depending on your use case.

Here is the code example:

```html
 Future<void> scheduleNotifications({
    required String description,
    required String coralId,
  }) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      0,
      'repeating coral id: $coralId',
      'repeating description: $description',
      RepeatInterval.weekly,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: _androidNotificationDetails,
      ),
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    );
    // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    //   0,
    //   "Scheduled Title",
    //   description,
    //   tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(
    //     const Duration(minutes: 1),
    //   ),
    //   NotificationDetails(android: _androidNotificationDetails),
    //   androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    //   uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
    //       UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    //   payload: coralId,
    //   matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfMonthAndTime,
    // );
  }
```